# can we do batch/multiple transfer in once?

Tags: balances, transfer

I want to send the tokens to bulk/multiple accounts.

Do we have any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [pallet-utility](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/utility/src/lib.rs)'s extrinsics!